# Can I have a window showing the diff or diffstat of the selected commit in the log window?

Tags: magit

I know I can press Enter to show the commit diff, but

1. that's too slow for browsing
2. it steals focus from the log window
3. there's a lot of visual change in the frame with the diff window opening and closing
4. It's a lot of keystrokes to move from one commit's diff to the next

Can I program magit to a gitk kind of style that always shows the commit msg, changed files and diff of the currently selected commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just navigate the log window with <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd>. The diff window will auto-popup and auto-update.  There's currently a bug that prevents scrolling by holding <kbd>n</kbd>. It's possible to use the previous Magit version to avoid this bug.

Comment: Thanks, that does it for me! Note for spacemacs users: `n` in `C-n` and `p` is `C-p`.

Comment: The command is `magit-go-forward`/`magit-go-backward`. It's mapped to `C-j` and `C-k` in some versions of specemacs.

Comment: not in "some" versions of spacemacs, but the ones using evil mode, cause j/k are vim key-bindings

Answer (score 1):

When moving inside the log buffer using <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>p</kbd>, then the revision buffer is automatically updates to show the commit at point. This can be controlled using the option `magit-diff-auto-show`.

Until a little while ago that did not work well when *holding* down one of these keys, because that caused the revision buffer to be updated for each commit moved over in the log buffer. I just pushed a kludge for that, which works by delaying updating the revision buffer. You might want to customize the new option `magit-diff-auto-show-delay` in order to fine-tune the delay.

Alternatively you can configure `magit-diff-auto-show` to *not* automatically update the revision buffer. If you do so you can still display the commit at point in the revision buffer by pressing either <kbd>RET</kbd> or <kbd>SPC</kbd>. The former makes the revision buffer the current buffer, the latter does not.